# Node Color Codes, What do they mean?

Tags: node-editor

Question: Is there a meaning to the Nodes Color Coding?

I've made a .blend file with all the Geo Nodes grouped, framed and labeled by their respective order in the ADD menu. In doing so, I don't understand the color coding of the Nodes. Take curves there, a mix of Teal and Red. But Red shows up in other categories. This is true with Teal, it's all over the place.
[image]

Comment: are you referring to the color of the headers (the section of the node with the label), the bodies (the other section) or the noodles?  Header colors are by "category" and the choice of what node goes with what category is more or less arbitrary.  You can control header colors in preferences under themes. Body colors are up to the user.  Noodle colors do have meaning. [This article](https://www.blendernation.com/2021/10/24/node-editor-ui-update-colored-noodles-and-customizability/) describes the color convention for noodles.

Comment: @Marty Fouts Yes the Header Color of each Node. Yeah thanks, I do know you can change the colors. Thanks for that link for the Noodels, anything like that for the Nodes?

Comment: Not really.  The nodes are supposedly grouped by color into 'similar' categories.  You can find the category list in preferences -> Themes -> Node Editor but that's really all the 'documention' I've found.

Answer (score 5):

For completeness, here is my entire answer.  Here are two nodes, connected by a noodle:

[image: Two nodes connected by a noodle]

There are also three unlabeled noodles coming into the image from the left.

There are three colored areas.

1. Noodles - starting in 3.0 Noodles are colored to reflect the sockets they are connecting and give some indication of what translations are being performed "behind the scenes."  [Node Editor UI Update: Colored Noodles and Customizability](https://www.blendernation.com/2021/10/24/node-editor-ui-update-colored-noodles-and-customizability/) on Blender Nation discusses Noodle colors in more details.  Prior to 3.0 Noodles were always the same color.
2. Body -- The body color can be varied node by node in the node editor side panel:

   [image: Node Editor Side panel showing the color option highlighted]
3. Header -- The color of the header reflects the "Category" that the node is from.  You can find and customize a list of header colors in Preferences → Themes → Node Editor:

   [image: Node categories and their colors]

The categories are supposed to group similar kinds of nodes together.  For example Curve and Mesh primitive nodes all have the same category and color (Geometry Node).

Answer (score 2):

@Marty Fouts You had the answer, Under Preference/Themes/Node Editor each color has a name for the color. thanks